# How to get the last three days excluding holidays (french) and weekdays in SQL or PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a sql script that select the last three dates from current day in my base like below :

```
select distinct file_date 
from my_database 
where file_date > DATEADD(DAY, -3, CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME()));
```

This is correct for me just in Wednesday, Thursday and Friday, BUT in Monday i wanna excluding the weekdays 
For **Monday** for example, I wanna just the file_date for Friday and current Monday .and For **Tuesday**, I wanna just the file_date for Tuesday and Monday only. 
How can I excluding the holidays and weekdays.
Thanks for Help.

Comment: You might want to start here for "Holidays" as it is a complex problem: https://github.com/azuyalabs/yasumi

Comment: build your own calendar table !

Comment: The DATEPART function can help you easily exclude a specific day such as Saturday, Sunday, etc but for holidays you will need to build your own holiday table as suggested by @ Squirrel

Comment: What format is the file_date field?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. so there is no function that can do that.

Comment: No ready to use functions but there are many ways to achieve it. Will post a answer with one or 2 ways.

Answer (score 0):

No sample data and DB structure, also i asumed you have MYSQL DB so i will just give a hint how to do it in MYSQL
You can use  [WEEKDAY()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) as filter for the days of week.
For example this in normal query filter the results only for monday to friday:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE WEEKDAY(date_field) < 5
```

You can also do it in php. Increase your results to 5 rows (to include the possible weekends) and order the results by descending date.

```
//you have $results array with 5 elements
$lastThreeDays = [];
$i = 0;
foreach ($results as $res) {
    $tStamp = strtotime($res['date_field']);
    $weekDay = date('N',$tStamp);
    if ($weekDay < 6 && $i < 3) {
        $lastThreeDays[] = $res;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

No you have 3 records of the last 3 days excluding the weekdays.

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try it